# Is displaying banner ad and interstitial on same activity is inline with Google admob policy?

Tags: admob

I would like to show both banner ad and interstitial on same activity. But i'm not sure if this will violate Google admob policy since when interstitial ad is displayed, it will cover the banner ad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is allowed. In fact, it's recommended you do this to increase earnings. What violates admob policy is placing two banners in one activity. A user should see one banner at a time. If it is a long screen, you can put one to the top, one to the bottom, so that user can see only one at a time.

Simply put, you can show both banner and interstitial ads on same activity but not two or more banners in same activity unless that activity contains something like a long scroll view

Comment: Thanks for this reply